# Trial Expiring Email frequency

Tags: interaction-design, email, accounts, trial-period

I am building a SAAS service which as a 30 day trial period. We know we need/want to notify trial accounts when the they are coming close to expiring.

But what is the right frequency?

We were thinking:

1. Week before expiration
2. Day before expiration
3. Day of expiration

Is this too much?

Comment: How long is the trial?

Comment: @BenBrocka - Edited my question to include it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your frequency is good, as long as there's an option to reduce that amount. That's strictly for the frequency, though.

My advice to you would be to NEVER send an email saying "hey, your trial is about to expire!" - this would be a wasted opportunity to take your users through some tasks that may be interesting to them. Tell them about a feature they haven't stumbled across yet. Explain how your product is most commonly used. Get creative with the emails and use it as a customized showcase for your user, and they might find the reminder emails (gasp) helpful!

Comment: The second part of your answer is really great. Thanks.